# How to compute multiple levels in python Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, division, depends

**What's wrong with my code ?**

***Requested:***

> If A annd B are 0 show me result = A

> > If A and B are not 0 then continue

> > > If C ID is 1 Do the equation

> > > Else if it's another ID then show me result = A

> Else of all just show A

***What i currently have (not working):***

```
@api.depends('A', 'B','C')
def _compute_X(self):
        for record in self:
            if int(record.A or record.B) != 0 and int(record.C) == 1:
                record.X = record.A / record.B
            else:
                record.X = record.A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `X`. I am considering them of type string class.

```
if int(record.A or record.B) != 0 and int(record.C) == 1:

        record.X = str(int(record.A) / int(record.B)) 
        # converting string to int while doing math operation and then converting the result to strting.
else:
    record.X = record.A
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! But added on the Field default as 1 so it doesn't get a divide error.